# Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, gmaps4rails

I'm using Gmaps4rails with Foundation 5.  I followed the Gmaps4rails video tutorial and the map is not showing up. I'm getting the `Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined` and the offending line is the first line of the custom script:

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
```

I assume there's some kind of conflict with Foundation because I tried creating a Rails app with only Gmaps4rails and no Foundation and everything works fine.

Comment: Are you sure you did include gmaps files in your pipeline?

Comment: Do you mean add `//= require underscore` and `//= require gmaps/google` to application.js?

Comment: Yes. Another potential issue is you have `Gmaps` called before the js files (order matters). Consider to put your js code in a dom ready callback

Comment: I'm sorry, what does 'putting your js code in a dom ready callback' mean?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=dom+ready+callback

Comment: So you're talking about the .ready() function, correct?  I guess I'm confused as to how I place underscore and gmaps/google into there.

Comment: just put everything inside so you're sure everything is loaded when your script is interpreted

Comment: I'm not sure what the syntax is to change `//= require gmaps/google` into syntax that goes in the .ready() function.

Comment: FWIW, I too have been trying to resolve this. Along the way, I have created some sample apps, including one with gmaps4rails, mongo, and zurb. I am not sure what corrections need to be done to avoid this error. But as soon as I find out I will broadcast the answer and have it up on github. https://github.com/JonKernPA/gmaps_zurb

Comment: $(function(){
  // your gmap codes! 
})

the '$(function(){})' will ensure that the javascript you included are loaded by your 'webpage' properly at first and then it will trigger the code.

Answer (score 7):

According to the sample app, the issue is the following: you call `Gmaps` before the script containing its definition is loaded... it cant work.

Explanation is you put `= javascript_include_tag "application"` at the bottom of your html, to meet Foundation's expectations. So every previous javascript will fail: you have to put your scripts after the files defining them.

So ***AFTER*** `= javascript_include_tag "application"`, add:

```
= yield :scripts
```

And then whenever you need in a view:

```
- content_for :scripts do
 :javascript
   // Gmaps can be called safely here...
```

Comment: Well this is weird.  The map shows up but it's all one color: blue and the Zoom icons are all messed up looking.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Benjamin!

I incorporated your suggestion and the map now shows up. Voila!

Checkout https://github.com/JonKernPA/gmaps_zurb to see a full sample app with:

- Ruby 2.0
- Rails 4.0
- gmaps4rails
- MongoDB
- Mongo_Mapper
- Haml
- Zurb Foundation 5.0